# Why does g++ 4.8.1 issue a conversion warning

Tags: c++, gcc

When I compile the code below with g++ 4.8.1 (64bit) in this way:

```
$ g++ -Wconversion -o main main.cpp
```

I get this result:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:20: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘long unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   int i = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
                    ^
```

My expectation would be that the compiler should be able to evaluate the expression at compile time. If you make a similar program in plain c, gcc works like a charm.

Should this be considered a bug in g++ (e.g. clang++ does not have this problem)?

if you change the problematic line to something like:

```
char c = 0x10000000/0x1000000;
```

then the compiler does not complain. This suggest that some constant evaluation is done before warning generation.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
};

foo x[50];

int main()
{
  int i = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
  std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that just without optimisation? Try `-O2` and it should evaluate it at compile time.

Comment: I do get the warning in 4.8 too, but I don't in what will become 4.9 (GCC sources from about a week ago), so I think the GCC devs do consider this a bug and have fixed it already.

Answer (score 7):

```
 int i = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
 //int <-- std::size_t <-- std::size_t / std::size_t
```

The type of the expression `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` is `std::size_t` which on your machine is `unsigned long int`. So conversion from this type to `int` is data-loss, if the source is bigger in size than the target.

Though, I agree that in your case, there would **not** be actual data-loss if the compiler *actually* computes the value, but I guess it applies `-Wconversion` before the *actual* computation.

Comment: It looks like the warning is on the division, though. It should still be dividing two `unsigned long int`s at that point, shouldn't it? Or does the expected assignment to an `int` cast it before the division (!)?

Comment: The division is the problem because it is the result of that operation that is converted to `int`. The division itself is safe.

Comment: Can anybody provide a standard quote that says evaluating an expression at compile-time can ignore the other rules in the standard? I can only find a note that it's okay for floating point operations to give different results since floating point precision is not specified. Why would the conversion in this question not be subject to the standard conversion rules?

Comment: @sftrabbit: What I mean is that the RHS cannot overflow `int`, as its value turn out to be `40` (size of the array) which is compile-time constant. So the warning, even though makes sense from type-point of view, is superfluous from actual-value-point of view (which is known to the compiler).

Comment: @Nawaz Oh, that makes sense. Good point. I do keep seeing suggestions around though that compiler-time evaluations are somehow exempt from some rules.

Comment: It's probably simply the compiler's warning trigger being unsophisticated, producing a warning about _anything_ unsigned converted to _anything_ signed under the premise that it _could_ produce a problem (even when it's observably a non-issue here).

Comment: @Damon That would make sense, but it's not. In fact, even though `int i = sizeof(int) / 2;` gives me the same warning, `int i = (sizeof(int) == 4 ? 4 : sizeof(int)) / 2;` does not, showing that the condition `sizeof(int) == 4` is properly evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof()` returns you `std::size_t` not `int`! So cast it or declare `i` as `std::size_t`.

```
 std::size_t i = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);
```